# Scaling in JavaFX and ScrollPanes

Tags: javafx-2

I've been trying to work with the scaling transform in JavaFX, but haven't quite been able to wrap my head around it. Basically, I have a Pane containing a complex graph and would like to be able to rescale it. The scaling part itself works fine, however, the enclosing scroll pane will not adapt to the graph.

For simplicity's sake, i'll post a short example in which my graph is replaced by a label:

```
public class TestApp extends Application {
    @Override public void start(final Stage stage) throws Exception {
        final Label label = new Label("Hello World");
        label.getTransforms().setAll(new Scale(0.5, 0.5));

        label.setStyle("-fx-background-color:blue");
        label.setFont(new Font(200));

        final ScrollPane scrollPane = new ScrollPane();
        scrollPane.setContent(label);

        stage.setScene(new Scene(scrollPane));
        stage.setWidth(200);
        stage.setHeight(100);
        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Application.launch(args);
    }
}
```

The label will scale correctly, but the enclosing scroll pane's bars will still accomodate a component of the original size.

I've tried so far:

- Playing around with the labels min and pref size
- wrapping the label inside a Group (no scrollbars will appear whatsoever)
- scaling the enclosing Group rather than the label

What am I missing? What can I do to make the ScrollPane adapt to the content view?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Scalable, pannable scrollpane: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44314455/1386911

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I implemented scaling in a ScrollPane for Graphs and other nodes in 
[this example of scrollpane viewports, transforms and layout bounds in JavaFX](https://gist.github.com/1442298).

The code was implemented when I was first learning JavaFX, so certainly the code could be cleaner and perhaps there are simpler ways to accomplish this (e.g. using a Group as the container for the scaled node as suggested in the [ScrollPane documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/control/ScrollPane.html)).

One key to getting the solution I wanted (ScrollBars only appearing when you are zoomed in and the node is larger than the visible viewport), was this code:

```
// create a container for the viewable node.
final StackPane nodeContainer = new StackPane();
nodeContainer.getChildren().add(node);

// place the container in the scrollpane and adjust the pane's viewports as required.
final ScrollPane scrollPane = new ScrollPane();
scrollPane.setContent(nodeContainer);
scrollPane.viewportBoundsProperty().addListener(
  new ChangeListener<Bounds>() {
  @Override public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Bounds> observableValue, Bounds oldBounds, Bounds newBounds) {
    nodeContainer.setPrefSize(
      Math.max(node.getBoundsInParent().getMaxX(), newBounds.getWidth()),
      Math.max(node.getBoundsInParent().getMaxY(), newBounds.getHeight())
    );
  }
});

...

// adjust the view layout based on the node scalefactor.
final ToggleButton scale = new ToggleButton("Scale");
scale.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
  @Override public void handle(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
    if (scale.isSelected()) {
      node.setScaleX(3); node.setScaleY(3);
    } else {
      node.setScaleX(1); node.setScaleY(1);
    }
    // runlater as we want to size the container after a layout pass has been performed on the scaled node.
    Platform.runLater(new Runnable() { 
      @Override public void run() {
        nodeContainer.setPrefSize(
          Math.max(nodeContainer.getBoundsInParent().getMaxX(), scrollPane.getViewportBounds().getWidth()),
          Math.max(nodeContainer.getBoundsInParent().getMaxY(), scrollPane.getViewportBounds().getHeight())
        );
      }
    });
  }
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. The code produces some rather strange side effects (e.g. when reducing the scale, the scroll bars will not adapt correctly until moved), but the approach is surely correct. This helped me a lot.

Answer (score 12):

According to the ScrollPane document you might try to wrap a Pane in a Group so the ScrollPane is scroll by visual bound not the actual layout bound.

```
ScrollPane layout calculations are based on the layoutBounds rather than the
boundsInParent (visual bounds) of the scroll node. If an application wants the
scrolling to be based on the visual bounds of the node (for scaled content etc.),
they need to wrap the scroll node in a Group.
```