# Responsive scrollPane zooming by mouse position

Tags: javafx, scroll, javafx-8, zooming, scrollpane

I need zoom in/out in ScrollPane relative to mouse position.  for that I used  [answer of this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39827911/javafx-8-scaling-zooming-scrollpane-relative-to-mouse-position), so far everything is fine. 
I need another thing too , when I fullSreen the window Vbox fill the whole page. for that change this little part of code : 1. set max size of Group to Double.Max_value :

```
public panelable(Node target) {
    super();
    this.target = target;
    this.zoomNode = new Group(target);
    zoomNode.maxHeight( Double.MAX_VALUE) ;
    zoomNode.maxWidth( Double.MAX_VALUE) ;
    setContent(outerNode(zoomNode));
    setPannable(true);
    setFitToHeight(true); //center
    setFitToWidth(true); //center
    updateScale();
}
```

2.declare vgrow for VBox :

```
  private Node centeredNode(Node node) {
    VBox vBox = new VBox(node);
    VBox.setVgrow( node , Priority.ALWAYS);
    vBox.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
    return vBox;
}
```

but Group isn't resizable and this code isn't working .Furthermore, as [Oracle ScrollPane documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/control/ScrollPane.html)  saying in my case need to wrap the scroll node in a Group. so, what can i do? is there a solution? help me please.
this is my main class code :

```
public class Main extends Application {
@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception{
    StackPane stackPane = new StackPane() ;
    stackPane.setPrefSize( 600, 600);
    stackPane.setMaxSize( Double.MAX_VALUE ,  Double.MAX_VALUE);
    stackPane.setStyle( "-fx-background-color: red");
    primaryStage.setScene(new Scene( new panelable( stackPane)));
    primaryStage.show();
}
public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}}
```

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: https://github.com/sedj601/ZoomNodeTest